# If $M \otimes N$ is flat and $M$ is flat, then $N$ is flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

So I was wondering if the product of two modules is flat then one of them being flat implies the other one is flat too. I think the answer is affirmative and I will try to present my reasoning here. I would be really glad if I got a confirmation that my reasoning is correct and this is indeed true or if someone pointed out at a mistake.

---

Suppose $M \otimes N$ and $M$ are flat. We'll take an injection $0 \to K \overset{f}{\to} P$ and show that $0 \to K \otimes N \to P \otimes N$ is an injection, thus proving that $N$ is flat.

Suppose there is a nonzero $\sum_i k_i \otimes n_i \in K \otimes N$, such that $\sum_i f(k_i) \otimes n_i = 0 \in P \otimes N$. Then after tensoring with $M$ on the right we get that for any $m \in M$ $$\left(\sum_ik_i\otimes n_i\right)\otimes m \in \ker \left(f \otimes \mathrm{id}_{M \otimes N}\right).$$
Thus, because $f$ is injective and $M \otimes N$ is flat, $\forall m \in M \: \left(\sum_ik_i\otimes n_i\right)\otimes m = 0$.

But I believe it contradicts our assumption that $\sum_ik_i\otimes n_i \neq 0$ and $M$ is flat. Indeed, cyclic module generated by $\sum_ik_i\otimes n_i$ injects into $K \otimes N$ thus, by flatness of $M$, $\left(\sum_ik_i\otimes n_i\right) \otimes M$ must inject into $K \otimes N \otimes M$, but we just saw that it the whole submodule becomes zero in $K \otimes N \otimes M$. We have arrived at a contradiction, thus proving our claim to be true.

---

P.S. If this is true, than this very easily shows that wherever $M$ is a flat $R$-module and $I = \mathrm{Ann}\,M$, then $R/I$ is flat. That is because $R/I \otimes M = M$ is flat and $M$ is flat.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, e.g. $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = 0$.

Comment: @Legendre is zero considered a flat module?

Comment: Yes, but if you'd like we could also do $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @AlekseiKubanov The zero module satisfies the definition of flat module, doesn't it?

Comment: @Legendre yes I see. thank you. going to search for a mistake in my proof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the quick way to see this cannot be correct is to observe that the zero module is flat.  In particular, if $M=0$ then both $M$ and $M\otimes N=0$ are flat but $N$ could be anything.  The error in your proof is that while it is true that $C\otimes M$ injects into $K\otimes N\otimes N$ where $C$ is the cyclic module generated by $\sum k_i\otimes n_i$ and every element of $C\otimes M$ goes to $0$ under this map, this does not tell you that $\sum k_i\otimes n_i=0$.  Indeed, even if $C$ is nonzero, $C\otimes M$ could be $0$ (which is what happens if $M=0$).

What your argument shows is that if $M\otimes N$ is flat and $M$ is *faithfully flat* then $N$ is flat.  (Faithfully flat means that both $M$ is flat and that if $M\otimes C=0$ for any module $C$ then $C=0$.)

Comment: Nice Work!!! Sir